# Using list comprehension to add one to a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nltk, list-comprehension

I'm trying to get rid of this for loop and instead use list comprehension to give the same result.

```
fd= nltk.FreqDist()
html = requests.get("http://www.nrc.nl/nieuws/2015/04/19/louise-gunning-vertrekt-als-voorzitter-bestuur-uva/")
raw = BeautifulSoup(html.text).text
for word in nltk.word_tokenize(raw):
    freqdist[word.lower()] += 1
```

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I can't get it to work because of the +=1. I've tried:

```
[freqdist[word.lower()] +=1 for word in nltk.word_tokenize(raw)]
```

But that will only raise an error. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: List comprehension creates a new list. It doesn't seem like you want to create a list here.

Comment: What is wrong with the `for` loop? List comprehensions are for creating lists, not a substitute for `for` loops; it looks like you're trying to make use of a side effect.

Comment: @asongtoruin thanks, I totally forgot about Counters. That did the job.

Comment: @roganjosh it's for an assignment where I'm asked to rewrite the code with list comprehensions.

Comment: You are not building a list, so don't use a list comprehension. Just stick to the loop, it is *more than fine*, and the best tool you have for this operation. That, or use a `collections.Counter()` object to do the looping and counting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to *mutate* an existing list/dictionary, using a list/dictionary comprehension is considered bad style because it creates an unnecessary throwaway-list/dictionary.

To be precise, I'm talking about the following:

```
>>> demo = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> freqdist = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
>>> [freqdist.__setitem__(key, freqdist[key] + 1) for key in demo]
[None, None, None]
>>> freqdist
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

As you can see, doing what you describe is possible, but that's not how you should do it because

- it is hard to read
- it creates an unused throwaway list `[None, None, None]`
- list comprehensions should be used to build a new list that you actually need

Creating a new dictionary with a dictionary comprehension is cumbersome as well, because not every value should be incremented (only the ones in `demo`).

You *could* do

```
>>> demo = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> freqdist = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
>>> freqdist = {k:v + (k in demo) for k,v in freqdist.items()}
>>> freqdist
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

However, we have suboptimal runtime complexity now because for each key in `freqdist` we do a O(`len(demo)`) membership test for `demo`.

You *could* use a `set` for `demo` to reduce the complexity of the dictionary building to O(`len(freqdist)`), but only if the elements of `demo` are unique.

```
>>> demo = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> freqdist = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
>>> freqdist = {k:v + (k in demo) for k,v in freqdist.items()}
>>> freqdist
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

I don't think this solution is particularly elegant, either.

In conclusion, your `for` loop is perfectly fine. The only good alternative would be to use a `Counter` object that you update:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> demo = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> freqdist = Counter({'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2})
>>> freqdist.update(demo)
>>> freqdist
Counter({'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1})
```

This is the solution I would use personally.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
>>> txt = 'Hello goodbye hello GDby Dog cat dog'
>>> txt_new = txt.lower().split()
>>> print txt_new
['hello', 'goodbye', 'hello', 'gdby', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog']
```

Now use `collections`

```
>>> import collections 
>>> collections.Counter(txt_new)
Counter({'hello': 2, 'dog': 2, 'gdby': 1, 'cat': 1, 'goodbye': 1})
```

If you are *not* allowed to use `collections.Counter` then:

```
>>> {word: txt_new.count(word) for word in set(txt_new)}
{'goodbye': 1, 'dog': 2, 'hello': 2, 'gdby': 1, 'cat': 1}
```